# Simplest way to get count of keys with a particular value

Tags: javascript

**Given a javascript object, what is the simplest way to get the number of keys with a particular value?**

For example, I have the following javascript object (where the key indicates a test script id and the value indicates the result of the script execution):

```
var result = {1: "PASS", 2: "PASS", 3: "FAIL", 4: "PASS", 5: "FAIL"};
```

I would like to get the count of keys with the value "PASS" (3 in this case) in the simplest way possible.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use Object.keys and Array.filter:

```
var result = {1: "PASS", 2: "PASS", 3: "FAIL", 4: "PASS", 5: "FAIL"};
var passCount = Object.keys(result).filter(function(key){
   return ( result[key] === 'PASS' );
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countKeys(data, expected) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key] == expected).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
}
```

Take the [object's keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), compare each one and convert to a boolean, then add the booleans together (coerces them to 0 for false, 1 for true, and sums).

With ES5, breaking this down, you can:

```
function countKeys(data, expected) {
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  var checked = keys.map(function (key) {
    return data[key] == expected;
  });
  return checked.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur;
  }, 0);
}
```

or with the even-older loops:

```
function countKeys(data, expected) {
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    var value = data[key];
    if (value == expected) {
      ++count;
    } else {
      // do nothing or increment some failed counter
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I had tried the third one myself before posting the question, but felt it was too lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter and get the length.

```js
var result = { 1: "PASS", 2: "PASS", 3: "FAIL", 4: "PASS", 5: "FAIL" };

function getCount(s, o) {
    return Object.keys(result).filter(function (k) { return o[k] === s; }).length;
}

document.write(getCount('PASS', result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = {1: "PASS", 2: "PASS", 3: "FAIL", 4: "PASS", 5: "FAIL"};

undefined

function getCountByValue(obj,value){
  return Object.keys(result).filter(function(key){
  return result[key] === value

}).length

}

//as your wish
getCountByValue(result,'FAIL')
getCountByValue(result,'PASS')
```